# Tagging deities and other figures

Tags: discussion, tags

I see we have a [zeus](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zeus) tag, which has been used in a couple questions.

There are twelve main gods and goddesses in Greek mythology, along with a host of other beings (titans, centaurs, sirens, Cyclopes, etc.). Do they all deserve their own tags?

There may be a decent number of questions about [hercules](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hercules), but not as many as, say, [telemachus](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telemachus). Should the latter deserve a new tag, or not? At what level if importance do we stop?

Comment: I happened to post my opinion on this on the other tagging question, so linking here: http://meta.mythology.stackexchange.com/a/120/87

Comment: How about rule of 3?

Comment: @Piper What do you mean?

Comment: On another site, not SE, I manage tags - and rule of three means to create a tag if it would have been used 3 times. So, three questions on Ares would mean an Ares tag is created and then added on to the three existing questions.