# Which tag to use for Biblical tales?

Tags: discussion, tags

Which tag we should use for Biblical stories?

My initial idea was to use [bible](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible) (because of simplicity) tag for myths described in the Bible. However it was changed to [abrahamic-religions](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abrahamic-religions) instead. In my opinion this tag is not so obvious for new people.

Should we use [abrahamic-religions](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abrahamic-religions), [bible](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible), or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Why not use both?

Comment: Are such questions relevant to Mythology, Christianity, Mi Yodeya, Hermeneutics, or Philosophy? Seriously doubt they are on-topic here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've seen the tag [judeo-christian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judeo-christian) a few times, and imo that one strikes a better balance between familiarity and accuracy/comprehensiveness.

I'm also under the impression that the gap between Judeo-Christian and Islamic myths is significantly larger than that between Judaist and Christian myths, so we don't really *need* to put all three under a single tag all the time (maybe only when the question explicitly covers all three?), but I could be wrong about that.

---

Incidentally, I think it makes sense to have a Bible tag in addition to [judeo-christian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judeo-christian). You could ask questions about Judeo-Christian myths that aren't in the Bible at all, or are only in the [apocrypha](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apocrypha), or only in the "canonical" [bible](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible). And some people will definitely be more knowledgeable about some of those categories than others (eg, what little I know is all from the canonical Bible). [I would be skeptical about tags for individual books and characters in the Bible](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/what-tags-should-we-avoid/120#120), but the Bible itself seems pretty useful.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @Ixrec's answer. I'm answering myself to add that the question about whether we should have [bible](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bible) vs [judeo-christian](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judeo-christian) is **an entirely different question**; it is the question about whether we should have tags for really narrow aspects of particular cultures.

That particular question has already been discussed in two places (I've VTCed the second as a dupe)

- [Should we have tags for specific elements in a culture?](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/11)
- [Tagging deities and other figures](https://mythology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122/tagging-deities-and-other-figures)